# Semantic Versioning - Backward compatibility and version 0.x.y

Tags: installation, version, backwards-compatibility, software-distribution, semantic-versioning

Here is an excerpt about [IBM mainframes](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/linuxonibm/liaag/wkvm/wkvm_c_overview.htm):

> The IBM Z family maintains full backward compatibility. This means that current systems are the direct, lineal descendants of System/360 announced in 1964, and System/370 from the 1970s. Many applications written for these systems can still run unmodified on the newest IBM Z system over five decades later!

I am sure that, there will be disclaimers, 'ifs', 'buts' around the claim of backward compatibility. But, for argument sake, if IBM Z were to support semantic versioning, would it have made beyond `0.y.z` ever? And, therefore, can the major integer be incremented if a major feature is released and the complete release is *still* backward compatible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am sure that, there will be disclaimers, 'ifs', 'buts' around the claim of backward compatibility. But, for argument sake, if IBM Z were to support semantic versioning, would it have made beyond 0.y.z ever?

Yes, but why would they do that?  Their own propaganda makes claims of backward compatibility, and the `0.y.z` form explicitly makes no such claims.  From the [SemVer 2.0.0](https://semver.org/):

```
[4](https://semver.org/#spec-item-4) Major version zero (0.y.z) is for initial development. Anything MAY change at any time. The public API SHOULD NOT be considered stable.
```

Not exactly the message that IBM is communicating.

> ...can the major integer be incremented if a major feature is released and the complete release is still backward compatible?

Yes.  There is nothing in the spec that says you can't bump the major version for any arbitrary reason.  The spec says you MUST bump it if you make a breaking change, not that it can only be bumped for that reason.

---

I would add that the Z machine hasn't been around since the 60's.  IBM makes claims that it is backwards compatible with those other machines that it made in the past.  Speaking of a semantic version history, across different products, really doesn't make any sense.  What they are really saying is that, each of those earlier products, had an interface (machine language), that today's Z machine is capable of executing.